# Problems with ROS/Tutorials/ WritingServiceClient(python)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run tutorial , WritingServiceClient(python) on Hydro.  After rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_serr.py, I get the following errors :

from: can't read /var/mail/beginner_tutorials.srv
/home/brent/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py: line 4: import: command not found
/home/brent/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `(' /home/brent/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py: line 6:`   def handle_add_two_ints(req):'

The text was copied and pasted  from the tutorial text accept the line numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149916/problems-with-ros/tutorials/-writingserviceclient(python)/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/68326/naaj/) on 2021-01-20**:
you can find it [here](https://github.com/kunal15595/ros/blob/master/ros_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from beginner_tutorials.srv import *
import rospy

def handle_add_two_ints(req):
    print "Returning [%s + %s = %s]"%(req.a, req.b, (req.a + req.b))
    return AddTwoIntsResponse(req.a + req.b)

def add_two_ints_server():
    rospy.init_node('add_two_ints_server')
    s = rospy.Service('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts, handle_add_two_ints)
    print "Ready to add two ints."
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_two_ints_server()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Morpheus, add  #!/usr/bin/env python at your first line.

---

Originally posted by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) with karma: 74 on 2014-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgrallos](https://answers.ros.org/users/91433/mgrallos/) on 2022-03-07**:
Hi good day, encountered the same problem and I tried this solution but it still doesn't work. Any alternative?